# How to make website images editable

Tags: javascript, image, mysqli

I have a small websites with good numbers of images. The problem is all images change over the time. For example, I have an image of offer. This image might change to another so I need to change the image.

I would like to store all the images in directory and images path in database. I will add an edit button next to each image, when user click that, I would like to pass some parameters like `src` to function and have the function allowing me to change any image on the website to anything.

I think I have a way but I need help starting up. I have created images table and added images. How can i write a function which basically will allow me to change any website image to different image from database.

**EDIT 1**
Here is some code I did. Basically when user click the edit image, modal opens which has all the images from database. When user select the image, it will replace the 'src' attribute of clicked image. But when I refresh the page, the image goes back to original image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
 <img alt="Start timer" id="idimg2" class="classimg" src="css/icons/timer-stop.png">
  <div class="overlay"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning img-upload" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" imgid= "idimg2" imgclass="classimg" >
  Edit
</button></div>
</div>




<!--  Timer reason modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> 
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">A&G Signs - SCS</h3>
        <div class="text-center">
                    <h4>Select Image</h4>
                     <form id="timer-reason">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <?php
                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($images)) {
                                    ?>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $row['imagedir_img']; echo $row['image_img']; ?>" style="width:20%;" class="img-gallary">

                                    <?php 
                                     }
                                    ?>

                                 </div>
                                </div>
        </div>
      </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="group button">
                        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="submit-timer-reason" role="button" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".img-upload").click(function(){
     imdid = $(this).attr("imgid");
});

$(".img-gallary").click(function(){
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src");
    $("#"+ imdid).attr("src",imgsrc)

   });  

  });
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Hello Mark! I'm sorry that you've run into troubles and I am thrilled that you have reached out to the StackOverflow community for help.  Unfortunately, this is an un-answerable question -- especially by the limitations here.  If you could provide some specific code that you're having trouble with, the community will help out as best as possible.

Comment: At the bare basics that I can answer, your function needs to accept a string (the file path) for the new image and it also needs to target the image element you want to update.  `function updateImage( newPath ){ var img = document.getElementById('img1ID'); img.src = newPath; }`

Comment: So you are coding a CMS, requires backend code.

Comment: @epascarello -- my first thought was, "maybe installing wordpress (or another CMS) is the best solution?"

Comment: I have edited the original question. Please look at the heading "Edit1"

Comment: Ah, if your issue is that the JavaScript does not persist after a refresh -- then you definitely need to build in some sort of back-end service.  JavaScript lives and dies with each instance of a site.  On refresh, the site goes back to what it originally was -- it does not persist.  Ideally, you can do the JS update on the user's page, but you will then need to kick off something in the back-end to generate an updated version of your page with the new image(s)

Comment: ... potentially, you can craft a middle-tier service that you call when the image swap occurs. and that service updates the DB.  Then on refresh, the PHP page should re-query the database (now with the updated content) and generate a new page, reflecting the changes that have been made.

Comment: Thanks.I do have a images table and imagesallocation table.Images contains images; imagesallocation contains  page detials,foreign key of image. I can send an AJAX request when user change the image..but my question is..for every single image on the website; will do I have to have an seperate query which will pull that image out. So I will have an sql query which will get the image, i can use HTML to display the image and also image ID in attribute. When user select the different image, I can replace the image 'src' in database. But this way I will have to have an separate query for all images